# Will there be a memory or processing time difference between a class member function and a global function

Tags: c++, class, memory-usage, compilation

I'm writing a neuron network simulation program and every operation or additional byte per neuron scales insanely. I prefer C++ as a language over the others, but now I'm wondering if the class structure takes additional space or resources after compilation in comparison to C for example. If I have a :

```
class Neuron{
float some,variables,foo,bar;
//And some functions to compute the changes
void foo();
void bar();
}
```

will it be leaner to have a :

```
struct Neuron{
float some,variables,foo,bar;
}
void foo(Neuron*);
void bar(Neuron*);
```

or is it the same after compilation?

Comment: Virtual methods will have an extra level of indirection since they have to first jump to the vtable and find the function to call. Non-virtual methods should compile down to the same thing.

Comment: Also this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422830/structure-of-a-c-object-in-memory-vs-a-struct (tl;dr: The C++ standard guarantees that memory layouts of a C struct and a C++ class  will be identical as long as the C++ class/struct fits the criteria of being POD ("Plain Old Data"))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class Versus Struct](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97217/class-versus-struct)

Comment: Even if there was a difference between those two constructs, it is probably neglegtable for your case (as it is for 99,9% of all real world cases), and believe me, you don't want to use such minor differences as base for your design decisions. I guess you never heard the term "premature optimization"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The term Doc Brown gave is very applicable in this case :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use virtual functions, then there should be no (negative) performance or space impact on using C++ classes when comparing to C structs. The two snippets you gave as example should compile to (nearly) the same assembly code.<sup>1</sup>

If you add virtual functions to your classes, then there will be a slight memory overhead per object (about the size of a pointer) and a time overhead per call to a virtual function, because the call has to go through a dispatch table. It will also be an indirect jump, which might be slightly more costly on some processor architectures (in the order of a few clock cycles).

<sub>Note 1: The compiler may use a different method for passing the implicit `this` parameter than what is used for the other parameters, but that difference is in the order of choosing register A instead of B or passing in a register instead of on the stack.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

If I remembr well all global will be write on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ on Uninitialized Data Segment.

Class function member section will be exist only if you have create new instance of the class. So It wil be store in heap.

So i think Global function is faster than Class member function.

To me choose a address of global is faster than ask a first address memory (object) for look if it contains another address memory (member).

Comment: OP isn't suggesting globals, just POD (trivially-initialized) struct with free functions, versus class instance with methods.